# define access to different tabs depending usertype in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to create a rails app that serves different tables depending
on the type of user you are, lets say you are in charge of the inventory
so the app would show you the tables related to the inventories, the problem
is I don't know beforehand all the types of users there will be, so I need a **generic**
approach to the problem.

my actual User model looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id              :integer         not null, primary key
#  created_at      :datetime        not null
#  updated_at      :datetime        not null
#  password_digest :string(255)
#  remember_token  :string(255)
#  username        :string(255)
#  id_compania     :string(255)
#  type            :integer
#  name            :string(255)
#  admin           :boolean         default(FALSE)
#  empresa_id      :integer         default(1), not null
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id_compania, :username, :type, :password, :password_confirmation, :name, :empresa_id
  has_secure_password
  belongs_to :empresa

  before_save { |user| user.username = username.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token
  USERNAME_REGEX = /(^([a-z]{3})-([a-z\d]){5,}$)/

  validates :username, `enter code here`presence: true, length: { maximum: 15 }, format: { with: USERNAME_REGEX }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 8 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
  validates :type, presence: true, length: { maximum: 4 }
  validates :id_compania, presence: true, length: { maximum: 3 }


  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use single table inheritance for this. The only change you'd need to make to your schema would be to use a string for the type field instead of an integer. Someone wrote a [STI guide](https://github.com/ivanacostarubio/docrails/blob/f3801a1b2e685d04dfbe01decb3a0a9609e33da9/guides/source/single_table_inheritance.textile) for the Rails guides, but it was never completed for some reason. You should be able to get enough out of it though and stackoverflow has some great questions & answers on the topic.

With the column change in place, you'll want to create different subclasses of the User model:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

InventoryUser < User
  def tables
    # your logic
  end
end

AdminUser < User
  def tables
    # your logic
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks!, this really seems to help me with my problem!

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have a :type defined for a User.   If that's the case, then you could define a method that returns certain table(s) depending on the user type you're interested in. e.g,

```
def return_tables(usertype)
  if (usertype=="Admin")
    @tables =.....(some way to retrieve the columns you want)
  else
  :
  end
end
```

and you could call it by:

```
return_tables(user.type)
```